# How to select distinct count/select of multiple fields of a table with join

Tags: mysql, select, count

- There are two tables - Table1 and Table2
- along with other fields table Table1 has fields t11, t12, t13
- along with other fields table Table2 has fields t22
- all of these fields will have values either 1 or 0
- For each record on table Table1, there will be minimum one and maximum any number of records in Table2
- Primary Key of Table1 is added to Table2 as Foreign Key to maintain the data relation
- I need the count of records of:

  1. count of records that has values t11 = 0 in Table1
  2. count of records that has values t12 = 0 in Table1
  3. count of records that has values t13 = 0 in Table1
  4. count of records that has values t22 = 1 in Table2 and
  5. count of the records that has values t11=1, t12=1, t13=1 and t22=0

```
    I am currently using the below query to find the count:

    SELECT 
    SUM( CASE WHEN tbl.`t11` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) T11Count, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN tbl.`t12` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) T12Count, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN tbl.`t13` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) T13Count, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN (tbl.`t11` = 1 AND tbl.`t12`=1 AND tbl.`t13`=1 AND tbl2.`t22`='0') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) T1232Count, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN tbl2.`t22` = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) T22Count 
    FROM `Table1` AS tbl 
    JOIN JOIN `Table2` AS tbl2 ON tbl.`ID1` = tbl2.`ID2`
```

- This query returns the count based on the number of records in the Table2
- Like: if Table2 contains 3 records for a record of Table 1, it returns the count 3.

But,
- I need it to be counted as single only despite how many number of record be there in the Table2 with relation to a record in Table 1

**Sample Data and Desired Output:**

```
Table1
-----------------------------------

ID1(PK)     t11     t12     t13     t14
1           1       1       1       a
2           0       1       1       b
4           1       1       1       c
5           1       1       1       d
6           0       1       1       e
7           1       0       1       f
9           1       0       1       g
10          1       1       1       h
11          1       0       1       i
13          1       1       0       j
14          1       1       1       k



Table2
-----------------------------------

ID2(PK)     t22     t123     ID1   
1           0       z        1
2           0       y        2
3           0       x        4
4           1       w        4
5           0       v        5
6           0       u        6
7           0       t        7 
8           0       s        7
9           0       r        9
10          0       q        1
11          0       p        2
12          0       o        10
13          0       n        11
14          0       m        11
15          0       l        13
16          0       l        14


Expected Output:
-----------------------------------
T11Count     T12Count     T13Count     T1232Count     T22Count
2            3            1            4               1
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read this [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: would you please provide some sample data and your expected output?

Comment: what is am.`t22`? shouldn't it be tbl2.`t22` since "Table2 has fields t22" ? We also need to know if duplicates in table2 (regarding value in column PK) have different values for column `t22`

Comment: Show us the output you are getting, plus the output you desire.

Comment: @iLikeMySql -
Thank you for pointing out the error. Yes that should be tbl2.t22.
I have corrected it. And I have added the sample data and the desired output as well.

Comment: Since you are joining table2 and sum tbl2.`t22` the question is: do rows with the same value for column PK in table2 have different values for column `t22`. If not, you can use a subselect to remove duplicates and join the result like this (instead of joining table2 directly):
inner join (select ID2, t22 from table 2 group by ID2) as tbl2
on(tbl.ID1 = tbl2.ID2) . Since ID1 is Pk in tbl1 the query will use an index for the join and performance shouldn't be a problem

Comment: table1 and table2 are in one to many relationship. Every record of Table1 will have minimum one record and maximum any number of records in Table2. Table2.t22 can have both values 0 or 1 for the corresponding record in Table1

Comment: @iLikeMySql thank you. Query worked for me using the join with sub-query. In above case, ID2 is the primary key and ID1 is the foreign key. So, I have to use group by ID1 to get unique output.

Comment: You're welcome. I mixed up the Keys, my bad . Like you said, you have to group by ID1 -> inner join (select ID1, t22 from table 2 group by ID1) as tbl2 on(tbl.ID1 = tbl2.ID1)

Answer (score 0):

Query that worked for me:

```
SELECT 
SUM( CASE WHEN tbl.`t11` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) T11Count, 
SUM( CASE WHEN tbl.`t12` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) T12Count, 
SUM( CASE WHEN tbl.`t13` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) T13Count, 
SUM( CASE WHEN (tbl.`t11` = 1 AND tbl.`t12`=1 AND tbl.`t13`=1 AND tbl2.`t22`='0') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) T1232Count, 
SUM( CASE WHEN tbl2.`t22` = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) T22Count 
FROM `Table1` AS tbl 
JOIN ( SELECT ID2, t22 FROM `Table2` GROUP BY t22) tbl2 ON tbl.`ID1` = tbl2.`ID2`
```